# Android Java Volley Persisting the Session in Classic ASP

Tags: java, android, session, asp-classic, android-volley

I'm writing a simple app which logs onto my webservice and then downloads some information via SQL about the logged in user.

Currently I have a dependency on Google's Volley and can readily send off volleys, read the response, etc. However, the problem comes when ASP (backend) is creating a new session on each request, thereby clearing any set session variables.

I've tried to read the response back from the server to get the cookie, and then attach that as a header on any subsequent volley, but it's not working as expected. I need to figure out why my sessions aren't persisting.

**INIT**

```
String sSessionID = "";
```

**My Volley call**

```
  String urlLoginAttempt = SERVER_ADDRESS + PAGE_LOGIN + "?u="+username+"&p="+pw;

    Response.Listener responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
             Toast.makeText(ctx, "DEBUG\nVolley Session ID : " + sSessionID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlWithParams, responseListener, this.errorListener) {


        //Add an extra cookie value header into the request, if cookie variable has been set
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (!sSessionID.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                params.put("Cookie", sSessionID);
            }
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            //Volley can automatically get the session ID

            sSessionID = parseCookie(response.headers.get("Set-Cookie"));

            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }

        public String parseCookie(String cookie) {
            String[] splitCookie = cookie.split(";");
            String[] splitSessionId = splitCookie[0].split("=");
            String sCookie = splitSessionId[1];
            return sCookie;
        }
    };


    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    netQ.add(stringRequest);
```

- On first call, `sSessionID` is empty.
- As the first response is received (a login attempt), the "set-Cookie" header is stripped, parsed, and saved into the local variable `sSessionID`
- The actual response from the ASP backend is currently "1" or "0", depending on whether the correct username/password has been sent to the server. This works correctly. When the response is "1", the backend also sets some session variables
- When I try and re-login, I step into the code and see that the session id (cookie) has been changed, and no set session variables exist. This happens even though all subsequent requests I add a "Cookie" header with that same `sSessionID` to try and persist the session.
- An example `sSessionID` value would be the header value `HTTP_COOKIE: ASPSESSIONIDXXXXXXX=IAOPCEODJPBJGJXXXXXXX;` stripped down to `IAOPCEODJPBJGJXXXXXXXX`

**Login.ASP Page**

```
<%
//Attempt to set any session variable to begin a new session
session("userid")=-1

username=ucase(request.querystring("u"))
pw=request.querystring("p")

//for testing only:
if username="J" AND pw="pass" then
    session("userid")="188473"
    session("name")="Jammo"
    ...
    response.write("1")
else
    session("userid")=-1
    reponse.write("0")
end if
%>
```

**EDIT**
A little more overview of my environment. On my webserver I have `login.asp` and `getdata.asp`. If I send a volley onto getdata then the ASP page will try and see if the user is logged in my checking the session var `session("userid")`. If there is no value set, I assume there is no user logged in. The page will return a "0" and the app will switch the user back to my login tab. If there IS a value set in `session("userid")` then it will return data about the current user name (JSON format).

Session variables on ASP seem to be the sensible way to do this... As Volleys are stateless, in order to do this I seem to have to send in a custom header with the request to show the session variable ("Cookie" header). However, this isn't working as the returned session variable still changes with each volley response